# Google Custom Search CSE - Highlight results

Tags: css

How do you highlight the results search term on a google custom search?

Comment: Where it's very good of you to share your findings, this is more a place for questions and answers, you would do well by starting a blog and posting things like this here. +1 though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer by user [@ss888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423103/ss888).

I've just managed to workout using the Firefox add-on, Firebug, ([Original source here](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2008/11/styling-searchcontrol-guest-post.html)) - how to highlight the results search term on a google custom search.

Simply add this to your stylesheet, et voila - `.gsc-results .gs-snippet b { background-color:#ff3100; padding:0 3px; color:#FFF; }`

Hope this helps someone as I couldn't find anything on it.